# View PDF in new Tab

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I have a MVC application that I want to show a PDF when I click on a `<a>` tag. I'm passing the file path and file name to the server side. When I run locally it renders, but when I push to server it give me a 404 error. Any ideas?

Here is my client code, the data is the file path:

```
'<a href="/OCR/ViewPDF?file=' + data + '&name=' + url + '" target=_blank>' + url + '</a>';
```

Server side code:

```
public FileContentResult ViewPDF(string file,string name)
    {
        string FilePath = Server.MapPath(_file);

        WebClient User = new WebClient();

        Byte[] FileBuffer = User.DownloadData(FilePath);

        if (FileBuffer != null)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);
        }

    return null;
```

}

Comment: so is /OCR/ViewPDF a valid path on your server?

Comment: No it's Controller/Action

Comment: Are you using IIS for this? What do the permissions on the folder that is storing the files look like?

Comment: Is "data" a local path on the client computer?  The server is looking on its own hard drive, not the client's hard drive.

Comment: What is `_file`? I do not see you declare that variable in ViewPDF action method.